# Mailman: Is it possible to re-send bounced emails?

Tags: mailman

I've just installed a Mailman server to send newsletters, but I (foolishly) didn't wait long enough for the new dedicated subdomain to propagate through the DNS network before sending the first one, so now I have a lot of bounced emails :( (due to `Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command)`)

Since about half of the emails went through anyway, is it possible to tell Mailman to re-send the bounced ones, now that the DNS issue is settled?

Here's the Postfix log for one of those bounced emails:

```
Oct 30 10:07:02 localhost postfix/smtpd[28548]: 47C5EC4134: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Oct 30 10:07:02 localhost postfix/cleanup[28580]: 47C5EC4134: message-id=<5451FFA8.8010408@XXX.com>
Oct 30 10:07:02 localhost postfix/qmgr[14515]: 47C5EC4134: from=<lista_clienti-bounces@lists.XXX.com>, size=431670, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 30 10:07:02 localhost postfix/smtp[28562]: 47C5EC4134: to=<info@icos-group.it>, relay=smtp.XXX.com[XX.XXX.X.XXX]:25, delay=0.42, delays=0.05/0/0.21/0.16, dsn=4.1.8, status=deferred (host smtp.XXX.com[XX.XXX.X.XXX] said: 450 4.1.8 <lista_clienti-bounces@lists.XXX.com>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Oct 30 10:16:20 localhost postfix/qmgr[14515]: 47C5EC4134: from=<lista_clienti-bounces@lists.XXX.com>, size=431670, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 30 10:16:20 localhost postfix/smtp[29719]: 47C5EC4134: to=<info@icos-group.it>, relay=smtp.XXX.com[XX.XXX.X.XXX]:25, delay=558, delays=558/0.06/0.1/0.04, dsn=4.1.8, status=deferred (host smtp.XXX.com[XX.XXX.X.XXX] said: 450 4.1.8 <lista_clienti-bounces@lists.XXX.com>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Oct 30 10:26:20 localhost postfix/qmgr[14515]: 47C5EC4134: from=<lista_clienti-bounces@lists.XXX.com>, size=431670, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 30 10:26:20 localhost postfix/smtp[30860]: 47C5EC4134: to=<info@icos-group.it>, relay=smtp.XXX.com[XX.XXX.X.XXX]:25, delay=1159, delays=1158/0.03/0.34/0.05, dsn=4.1.8, status=deferred (host smtp.XXX.com[XX.XXX.X.XXX] said: 450 4.1.8 <lista_clienti-bounces@lists.XXX.com>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Oct 30 10:46:20 localhost postfix/qmgr[14515]: 47C5EC4134: from=<lista_clienti-bounces@lists.XXX.com>, size=431670, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 30 10:46:21 localhost postfix/smtp[320]: 47C5EC4134: to=<info@icos-group.it>, relay=smtp.XXX.com[XX.XXX.X.XXX]:25, delay=2359, delays=2359/0.03/0.1/0.04, dsn=4.1.8, status=deferred (host smtp.XXX.com[XX.XXX.X.XXX] said: 450 4.1.8 <lista_clienti-bounces@lists.XXX.com>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Oct 30 11:16:20 localhost postfix/qmgr[14515]: 47C5EC4134: from=<lista_clienti-bounces@lists.XXX.com>, size=431670, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 30 11:16:20 localhost postfix/smtp[3133]: 47C5EC4134: to=<info@icos-group.it>, relay=smtp.XXX.com[XX.XXX.X.XXX]:25, delay=4158, delays=4158/0.03/0.1/0.06, dsn=4.1.8, status=deferred (host smtp.XXX.com[XX.XXX.X.XXX] said: 450 4.1.8 <lista_clienti-bounces@lists.XXX.com>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Oct 30 11:16:20 localhost postfix/qmgr[14515]: 47C5EC4134: from=<lista_clienti-bounces@lists.XXX.com>, status=expired, returned to sender
Oct 30 11:16:20 localhost postfix/bounce[3136]: 47C5EC4134: sender non-delivery notification: 9CFC2C0560
Oct 30 11:16:20 localhost postfix/qmgr[14515]: 47C5EC4134: removed
```

Comment: Usually above error was means temporary error and any MTA should retry to send it until specified time. BTW, What MTA did you use with mailman?

Comment: @masegaloeh: I'm using Postfix, it tried for about an hour and a half, and then went to "status=expired" and stopped trying

Comment: Could you post sample of maillog/mailman log lines indicated `status=expired`?

Comment: @masegaloeh: sure! Added to the question

Comment: Are the never-sent emails still in mailman's (not sendmail's) cache directory? To answer your question literally, "yes, it is possible, because I've done it before". But it was painful.

Comment: @barrycarter: I see, so this is an unsupported use-case, as far as Mailman is concerned?

Comment: I think so. I remember posting it to the Mailman list ages ago and having Mark Sapiro himself reply (as he often does). However, I used a term different than "bounced". It may have been "stuck" (as in "stuck in the cache directory and never deleted"). Good luck :)

Comment: Strange, postfix gave up at just over an hour. This is not default behavior; by default it will keep trying for [five days](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#bounce_queue_lifetime). Show your postfix configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: well that's odd, I have a "maximal_queue_lifetime = 1h"... Must be some leftover from an old test :(

Comment: Well, looks like you are out of luck now because both postfix and mailman doesn't have a copy of your sent email. Better to resend email to mailman :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the error message

```
Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

indicated this is **temporary** error because of non-existent domain. DNS change *usually* propagate in 24 hours and by default postfix should **automatically** retry this delivery until `maximal_queue_lifetime` (the default value is 5 days).

As you accidentally set `maximal_queue_lifetime` to 1 hour, then postfix will **give up** after retried for 1 hour. Then postfix will send bounces to mailman.

Because of that you need to resend email to mailman. If you have configured **archive** in mailman list, then you can retrieve the original email there.